# How to select spatial layer by location and write to attributes?

Tags: python, gis, arcgis

I am compiling a global data set of oil wells. One of the necessary attributes is whether the well is located onshore or offshore. Only about 1/3 of our 20+ thousand records have this attribute populated. My question is: how can I auto-populate this field using the condition of containment within country borders as the determinent of a point's onshore or offshore location? I would prefer Python to SQL as we are still in File GDB format.

Cheers,
James

### Update

I must mention that I am fairly new to ArcPY, so I am not really sure to start with the code. These are point features stored as feature classes in a file GDB. I won't be back in the office again until Tuesday to post records, but the geospatial table is populated with Unique ID's, Lat-Longs, Elevations, Onshore/offshore, etc. That table is linked to three other tables through relationship classes which are determined by our type field. We have shapefiles for both country and ocean borders, so either topological truth would be fine to use as a condition.

Comment: Do you have a shapefile of the country borders?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please improve your question by making clearer what you mean, showing some code if possible. This will improve your chances for a good answer.

Comment: If feasible, could you post one of your data set's records? What data structure are you using to hold a record?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using Select by Location and Update Cursors.  The screenshot shows the result of the attached script.  The general idea here is to select the points that intersect land, and write to the attribute table "y" or "n" based on if the point is located on land.

[image]

---

```
import arcpy, os

ws = r'C:\temp\analysis.gdb\albers'

oilwells = r'C:\temp\analysis.gdb\albers\oilwells'
land = r'C:\temp\analysis.gdb\albers\usa'
oilwells_lyr = "oilwells_lyr"

# Make the first selection and write to attributes
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(oilwells, oilwells_lyr)
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management (oilwells_lyr, "INTERSECT", land, "", "NEW_SELECTION")

arcpy.AddField_management(oilwells_lyr, "land", "TEXT")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(oilwells_lyr, ["land"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = "y"
        cursor.updateRow(row)

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(oilwells_lyr, "oilwells_y_lyr")

# Make the second selection and write to attributes
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management (oilwells_lyr, "INTERSECT", land, "", "SWITCH_SELECTION")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(oilwells_lyr, ["land"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0] = "n"
        cursor.updateRow(row)

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(oilwells_lyr, "oilwells_n_lyr")

# Merge the two temp layers and create a permanent feature class
arcpy.Merge_management (["oilwells_y_lyr", "oilwells_n_lyr"], os.path.join(ws, "out_fc"))
```